# Grails i18n not working for locale "he" (Hebrew)

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am working on Grails i18n message. I have added code in resources.groovy

```
localeChangeInterceptor(ParamsAwareLocaleChangeInterceptor) {
    paramName = "locale"
}

localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) {
    defaultLocale = new Locale("en")
    java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
}
```

Added below messages in `messages_he.properties`

```
_appNav.apps.show-label-button.title    =   הצג תוויות
```

but it is not getting picked,

And `session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'`

above code gives `"iw"`

Comment: he_IL is what you need and you should have messages file for it

Comment: @vahid I don't think `_he_IL` should be required, should it?  I think just `_he` should also work.

Comment: The question mentions `messages_he.proerties` is that `.proerties` just a typo in the question or is that the actual file name?  The file name should end in `.properties`

Comment: @Jeff yes @ he works fine but I got into the habit of using full extension due to some other oddity : http://myprofessions.com/profile/smoothoperator?lang=fa vs http://myprofessions.com/profile/smoothoperator?lang=fa_IR there are other languages that behave similarly and the difference is the date numbers are not returned correctly for that given locale. In two example above the second shows numbers dates in persian..PS the limitation restriction being in icu4j libraries which is doing all the numerical changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working using this more complex way, params.lang=he_IL

It receives this then looks up

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils as RCU

Locale = getLocaleForLanguage(params.lang)
session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE' = locale
            session.language = locale.language
            session.locale = locale
            session.langConfirmed=true
            if (updateReq) {
                RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, locale)
            }



static Locale getLocaleForLanguage(String language) {
            if (language.contains('_')) {
                def splitLang=language.split('_')
                return 


Locale.getInstance(splitLang[0].toLowerCase(),splitLang[1].toUpperCase(),'')
            }
            return Locale.getInstance(language,'','')
        }
```

Then a relevant file called `messages_iw.properties`

It [works fine for me](http://myprofessions.com/?lang=he_IL)